# I want to delete a div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have two buttons, one button copy the `div` and add a new `div`, the second button should delete exactly the `div` where the button is clicked. but nothing happened

```
<div id="fullTable">
  <div class="row" id="row">test <button type="button" onclick="deleteRow()">-</button> <button type="button" onclick="duplicateRow()">+</button></div>
</div>

<script>
  function duplicateRow() {
    row = $("#row")
      .clone("#row")
      .appendTo("#fullTable");
    row.append(row);
  }
  function deleteRow() {
    row = $(this).closest(".row");
    row.remove();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Any reason you’re using event attributes `onclick` rather than jQuery event listeners?

Comment: did you debug an is `row`an actual element?

Comment: I don't know if this is the reason it's not working but this results in duplicate ID's which is invalid HTML and most of the time will cause issues

Comment: @Xufox hey, it works with event listener (click()) but why not with the button onclick?

Comment: @Xufox hey, it works with event listener (click()) but why not with the button onclick?

Comment: AFAIK `.clone()` doesn't take a selector as a parameter: https://api.jquery.com/clone/ Also sidenote: you should add an aria-label to your button `<button aria-label="delete row">-</button>` so screen readers can read a meaningful text (what this button does) to their users and not a meaningless "minus" or nothing when it's a :pseudo-generated icon ;)

Comment: @devDen Use `console.log(this)` to see what `this` is.

Answer (score 1):

Just add current object as parameter for `deleteRow` function. And use it in jquery selector to get closest `.row`

```js
function duplicateRow(){
  $('#row').clone().appendTo('#fullTable'); 
 }
 function deleteRow(obj){
  var $row = $(obj).closest('.row')
  $row.remove();
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "fullTable">
   <div class = "row" id="row">
     test
     <button type="button" onclick="deleteRow(this)">-</button>
     <button type="button" onclick="duplicateRow()">+</button>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" onclick="duplicateRow($(this))">+</button>

function deleteRow(btn){
    btn.closest('.row').remove();
}
```

To be sure, you need to indicate the element to the function!